# What's the best way to convert an array of ints into a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to convert an array of int (like this `[1, 1, 2, 1]`) into a string (`"1121"`).

What's the best (most pythonic) way to do this?

I could always do something like this then remove the extra brackets:

```
>>> str([1, 2, 1, 1])
'[1, 2, 1, 1]'
```

or I can do something like this:

```
s = ""
for i in [1, 2, 1, 1]:
    s += s(i)
```

But both methods feel a little shaky. Is there a better way to do it?

For the record, I'm naturally interested in all versions of Python, but I'm working on py2.7 and would prefer answers that work with this version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generator expression:

```
"".join(str(i) for i in l)
```

PS: your "array" is really a list.

Comment: Yes definitely a list. I'm just returning to Python after 6 months of intense C. That was bound to happen :s

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
l = [1, 2, 1, 1]
s = ''.join(map(str, l))
print(s)
```

Here, `map(str, l)` converts `l` into a list of strings, and `''.join(...)` merges the strings.

Comment: Alternatively, `''.join(str(x) for x in l)` which arguably reads neater (and avoids an intermediate list in Python 2.x, though that *could* be avoided with `itertools.imap`).

Comment: @delnan Since *str.join* makes two passes over the data, it runs faster if you give it a list to begin with.  This is one of the few cases where an intermediate list is always needed (if you don't provide one, *str.join* will have to build one itself).

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: +1 Interesting, didn't consider that (but it makes sense now - one pass for calculating the result string's size and one pass for building it). I'd probably still use a generator expression out of habit and for consistency.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: The implementation could have used O(n) `+=` or StringIO-like object to build a string from an iterable. Though using a sequence might be faster in a typical case.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 1, 1]
''.join(str(x) for x in lst)
```

It's efficient since it doesn't create an intermediate list (as `map` does), instead the list is traversed using iterators.

Answer (score 0):

This one is just for fun, since it only works when every element of a list is a single-digit integer:

```
lst = [1, 1, 0, 1]

def convert_to_str():
    new_num = 0
    for i in xrange(len(lst)):
        new_num += lst[i]*(10**(len(lst)-1-i))
    return str(new_num)
```

Comment: Or str( reduce( lambda a,b:a*10+b, lst))