# Adding newlines in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Does anybody know the syntax of turning a list of lists into something that looks like what I have drawn below?

The list of lists would look like so:

```
list = [0, [~, ~, ~], 1, [~, ~, ~], 2, [~, ~, ~] ]
```

And this is the desired output:

```
0 ~ ~ ~
1 ~ ~ ~
2 ~ ~ ~
```

I've seen other people ask a similar question however their sub-lists only had one element, and there were no integer elements in front of each sub-list either, and so they used the following in order to obtain the result that I need:

```
"\n".join(item[0] for item in list)
```

I'm not sure how to manipulate the above line of code to solve my specific problem. I tried changing

```
item[0] to item[0:len(sub_list)]
```

and many other things but nothing has worked. (I'm quite inexperienced with Python)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can always use explicit iteration by twos:

```
el = [0, ['~', '~', '~'], 1, ['~', '~', '~'], 2, ['~', '~', '~'] ]
for i in range(0, len(el), 2):
    print el[i], " ".join(el[i+1])
```

I cannot presently think of anything cleverer.

Answer (score 2):

Not as clever or concise as the other answers, but definitely readable:

```
# This function is taken from 
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

my_list = [0, ['~', '~', '~'], 1, ['~', '~', '~'], 2, ['~', '~', '~'] ]

paired = chunks(my_list, 2)

for index, lst in paired:
    print index, ' '.join(lst)
```

Comment: Make it `for index, lst in paired:`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's correct that definition:

```
lst = [0, ['~', '~', '~'], 1, ['~', '~', '~'], 2, ['~', '~', '~']]
```

Please, never use `list` as an identifier name. It shadows the builtin function `list`.

To make this easier to handle, convert it to a simple list of lists:

```
lst = [[lst[i]] + lst[i+1] for i in xrange(0, len(lst), 2)]
```

Then `join` that:

```
print "\n".join([" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in lst])
```

Comment: There is no need to use the square-brackets `[]` inside the `join()` method. You can pass it as a generator expression

Comment: `join` has to build a list anyway (to calculate the length of the resulting string), so it is usually faster to use the list comprehension instead of the generator expression.

Comment: @WolframH really? why does it need to calculate the length? do you have some link with the source code?

Comment: It has to allocate memory for the string. I didn't look at the source code, but it is stated quite often. Look here, for example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143506/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-an-array-of-ints-into-a-string/9143515#comment11494997_9143515 .

Comment: I'll take Raymond Hettinger's word for it. Put the `[]` back in.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a comprehension over the indices up to the length of the list

```
'\n'.join('%s %s' % (list[2 * i], list[2 * i + 1]) for i in [0:len(list)/2])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to group your list in groups of two. Then, I'm iterating over the sublist, and using [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join its elements with a whitespace, appeding it to the first element, and finally, joining all lines with a breakline (`\n`).

```
>>> my_list = [0, [11, 1.2, 'str1'], 1, [21, 2.2, 'str2'], 2, [31, 3.2, 'str3'] ]
>>> it = iter(my_list)
>>> my_str = '\n'.join((str(x) + ' ' + ' '.join(str(y) for y in l)) for x, l in zip(it, it))
>>> print my_str
0 11 1.2 str1
1 21 2.2 str2
2 31 3.2 str3
```

This solution will work with any kind of type in your list and sublists.

Answer (score 0):

If your list really has that exact structure (non-list element in even positions, list element in odd positions) you could do this:

```
def pairs(l):
    i = iter(l)
    while 1:
        yield (i.next(), i.next())
print '\n'.join(['%s %s' % (f, ' '.join(s)) for f, s in pairs(list)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the list in chunks (two items at a time) using standard ["grouper" idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks):

```
L = [0, ['~', '~', '~'], 1, ['~', '~', '~'], 2, ['~', '~', '~']]
print('\n'.join("%s %s" % (i, ' '.join(lst)) for i, lst in zip(*[iter(L)]*2)))
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/v34GA)

```
0 ~ ~ ~
1 ~ ~ ~
2 ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score 0):

Using no index and doing no creation of list nor sublist:

```
lst = [0, ['~', '~', '~'], 1, ['~', 889, '~'], 2, ['~', '~', ('a','b')], 3, ['#', '#'] ]

it = iter(lst)
print '\n'.join( '%s %s' % (x,' '.join(str(u) for u in next(it))) for x in it)
```

result

```
0 ~ ~ ~
1 ~ 889 ~
2 ~ ~ ('a', 'b')
3 # #
```