# Extract dates using BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

how to extract the date in this using BeautifulSoup?

```
<div class="month">                                            Dec                                          </div>                                             
<div class="edate">                                                 31                                             </div>                                             
<div class="day">                                                 Mon                                             </div
```

Comment: Are you sure that your HTML code is formatted correctly? Seems like an awful lot of whitespace... and the final close tag isn't properly closed. Copy+paste error?

Comment: it was just too many white spaces after the dates for the closing tags, so I didnt include it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the *parent* element of those divs, then get the three strings and join them into one string:

```
date = ' '.join([unicode(t) for t in parent.stripped_strings])
```

which would result in `Dec 31 Mon`.

If you need to manipulate the date, you'll need to parse it out to a `datetime.date` object; I strongly suggest you use the [`dateutil` external library](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) to do that. However, since the year is missing from this date, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Looks like the OP will have to be defaulting the year to something, but otherwise this works if there's a clearly defined parent (or at least someway to get month and edate classes reliably)

Comment: `[]` inside `join()` are unnecessary since Python 2.4 (I think)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Using a list inside a ''.join is defensible: ["Since str.join makes two passes over the data, it runs faster if you give it a list to begin with."](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9143515/190597)

Comment: @unutbu: Cool, didn't know `str.join()` built an intermediary list in that case. I'll revert the change.

Comment: @unutbu: a good find. If a profiler says so then `[]` could be used.